# Uber API PHP Longitude must be a float for dictionary value

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, uber-api

I am attempting to list nearby products using the Uber API in a PHP app I am using.

I've used an OAuth2 Library to get my access and refresh tokens, but upon trying to make the following call `https://api.uber.com/v1/products?latitude=51.556924&longitude=0.106405` I get the following error response

```
array(3) {
  ["result"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["fields"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["longitude"]=>
      string(46) "Longitude must be a float for dictionary value"
    }
    ["message"]=>
    string(15) "Invalid request"
    ["code"]=>
    string(17) "validation_failed"
  }
  ["code"]=>
  int(422)
  ["content_type"]=>
      string(16) "application/json"
}
```

It suggests to me that the issue relates to the longitude I have provided (the coords are the Arsenal Football Club box office outside their stadium in London).

Have I missed something?

Making a call to `https://api.uber.com/v1/me` returns the expected results. So I assume it's not the access token.

Thanks
-Chris

Answer (score 1):

Just add **&callback=?** at the end of your url i.e after longitude.